# How can we access RLP encoded signed raw transaction in solidity?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I know how to create a raw transaction for Ethereum because there are many articles like [this](https://medium.com/blockchain-musings/how-to-create-raw-transactions-in-ethereum-part-1-1df91abdba7c).

But I don't know how to access the raw transactions in Solidity.

Msg object give us msg.data, msg.sender, msg.sig and msg.value.
These parameters are convenient but I want the RLP encoded signed raw transaction.

How can I access the raw data?

Is there any global variable like tx.raw? 
Or Is it impossible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge, the raw transaction is not exposed to Solidity.